# CefSharp request.PostData is null in OnBeforeBrowse while posting form

Tags: c#, cefsharp

In CefSharp browser (C# WinForms) I want to fetch what user is POSTing I tried  request.PostData but it is null and I also tried request.Headers but it also is empty i.e. request.HeadersCount is 0 always.

My page link from which I am posting begins with protocol prefix file:///

```
    public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
    {
        if (request.Method=="POST")
        {
            //void is here
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You'll likely need to use a `standard scheme` like `http` or `https`, the `file` scheme behaves differently and is not suitable for such purposes.

Comment: If you need to load files from disk then use a `Custom Scheme` handler. examples in the source.